# Is the function $f(x)$ positive in $[0,1]$ where $ a, b>0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Is the function $$ f(x) = \frac {e^{-ax}}{ax} -\frac{e^{-abx}}{1- e^{-ax}}\left((1-x)\cos (\pi x)+\frac{3}{\pi} \sin(\pi x)\right)$$
positive in $[0,1]$ where $ a, b>0$

Comment: No
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+f%28x%29+%3D+%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B-1x%7D%7D%7Bx%7D+-%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7B-x%7D%7D%7B1-+e%5E%7B-x%7D%7D%5Cleft%28%281-x%29%5Ccos+%28%5Cpi+x%29%2B%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B%5Cpi%7D+%5Csin%28%5Cpi+x%29%5Cright%29

Answer (score 1):

Look at $x$ near zero.  Then note that

$$f(x) = \frac {e^{-ax}}{ax} -\frac{e^{-abx}}{1- e^{-ax}}\left((1-x)\cos (\pi x)+\frac{3}{\pi} \sin(\pi x)\right)=-\frac32+\left(b-\frac{2}{a}\right)+O(x)$$

So, we see that near zero, the function is negative whenever $b-\frac{1}{2a}<\frac32$.

Comment: I think that $-1$ should be $-\frac 32$.

Comment: @claudeleibovici You're correct.  I've edited accordingly.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: You are welcome !